# Achieve a high pass filter in blender compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

how can I Achieve a high pass filter like that one in photoshop with the blender compositor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using these instructions [from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter#Image):

[image]

If you want, then you can create a reusable [node group](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Node_Groups) by selecting the nodes and pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: @AlexanderBicukow It works fine for me in 3.1.2, in what way does it not work for you?

Comment: it's working, my bad