# Blender's invert node not working properly

Tags: compositing-nodes, shader-nodes

What's wrong with Blender's invert node and how to make it work like in photoshop?
I need to invert image like in photoshop, but blender don't want to do that
[image]
I thought, that problem is in color space (16 and 32 bit float), but there is no difference
[Original .exr image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KeOTUl_51h3dw2xcp6USG8jCPe_22wJx/view?usp=sharing)

I actually want to reproduce highpass filter like in this thread [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15862/achieve-a-high-pass-filter-in-blender-compositor), but without proper invert behavior this not working

Comment: You haven't made access to the file

Comment: *Crantisz, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Photoshop inverts colors in sRGB color space, while Blender do this in linear. So, maybe the good choice is convert colors to sRGB and the return it back like this:

[image]

Comment: Sadly, the result isn't the same as in photoshop, also not only with 32 bit float, inverting jpeg in sRGB gives the same problem

Comment: Hi @Crantisz :). This still gives slightly off result. But the more I play with different images and formats, the more I think Blender is either trolling us or buggy :)).

Comment: @AlexanderBicukow I guess the problem will be that Photoshop and Blender use different color management / profiles, so that the different will already be after converting to sRGB and not the inverting itself. When I try with a simple JPG, I have to set the _Color Space_ in the _Image Texture_ node to _Linear_ and then invert it - and it looks like in Photoshop.

Comment: This answer is actually correct
see this link for more info https://developer.blender.org/T98303

Answer (score 0):

you could divide a small value (I have used 0.005) by your image [image]

It's not the most accurate methode, but it looks okay